Configuring your server for PHP data streaming
I've developed a chat application based on the OpenAI API. Locally, I've written my application in such a way that the data is sent in streaming, bit by bit; this allows you to see the message being written bit by bit. My proxy.php file takes care of this on the backend, processed by React on the front :
<?php

ob_implicit_flush(true);
// Log all request details
file_put_contents('debug.log', print_r($_SERVER, true) . "\n\n" . file_get_contents('php://input') . "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);

// Liste des origines autorisées
$allowed_origins = array(
    'https://philogpt.vmirebeau.fr',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://localhost'
);

// Détecter l'origine de la requête
$origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] ?? '';

if (in_array($origin, $allowed_origins)) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $origin);
} else {
    // Par défaut, interdire l'accès si l'origine n'est pas autorisée
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null");
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    exit(0);
}

// Récupérer les données JSON
$json_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json_data, true);

// Vérifier si la clé 'input' existe dans les données JSON
if (!isset($data['input'])) {
    http_response_code(400); // Bad Request
    echo "Champ 'input' manquant dans les données JSON.";
    exit;
}

// Récupérer et assigner la valeur de 'input'
$input = $data['input'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Lire la clé API à partir de la variable d'environnement
$api_key = MY_API_KEY;
if (!$api_key) {
    http_response_code(500); // Internal Server Error
    echo "Clé API non trouvée.";
    exit;
}

// Préparer les données de la requête à envoyer à l'API GPT
$data = array(
    'model' => 'gpt-4o-mini',
    'stream' => true,
    'messages' => $input // Transmettre directement l'historique des messages reçu dans 'input'
);

// Définir les options curl pour la requête API
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key
    ),
    // Traiter chaque fragment de données au fur et à mesure qu'il arrive
    CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION => function($ch, $chunk) {
        echo $chunk;
        return strlen($chunk);
    }
);

// Initialiser la requête curl
$ch = curl_init();

// Définir les options curl spécifiées précédemment
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

// Exécuter la requête curl et fermer la connexion
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>

Unfortunately, when I deploy it on my ovh.com hosting (I have a basic “personal hosting” package, if that's relevant), the data streaming doesn't work: I only see the complete message arrive, once it's completely finished. This is a pity for the user experience, as it lengthens waiting times.
I tried unsuccessfully to configure my .htaccess:
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1
    # Disable buffering for this route
    SetEnvIf Request_URI “^/server/proxy.php” proxy-sendchunked
</IfModule>


# Disable compression to avoid interfering with streaming
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</IfModule>

# Enable CORS requests if necessary
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin “*”
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods “POST, GET, OPTIONS”
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers “Content-Type”
</IfModule>

# Avoid caching for proxy responses
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control “no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0”
</IfModule>

Do you have a solution?
Thank you,
Vivien

Ignoring curl for a bit, with buffering off try using echo 'something';, followed by sleep(10) and then echo 'test';. Skip react, too, just try this in your browser. If this doesn't work, it is a general server problem, and you might need to play around with additional headers maybe.

I could imagine that provider to have a front end balancing server gathering the full response into a bigger chunk before sending it out.
